# Please recommend rust solution for old gas stove with pilot light

Tags: gas, rust, gas-stove

Please let me know if you see concerning rust and what might fix it.[stove photo](https://share.icloud.com/photos/0cfambtH57wRUzZkst0WyBC4Q)

Comment: Are you planning on adding a few pictures anytime soon?